# How to generate a list of quadruples in prolog?

Tags: prolog

`1 < X < Y and X + Y <= 100.
S = X + Y
P = X * Y .`

The goal `s1(Q,100)` will bind `Q` with a list of quadruples `[X, Y, S, P]`, where
`S = X + Y` and `P = X*Y`.

I want to have an answer such as 
`Q = [[3,4,7,12],[2,6,8,12], ....]`

Please assist, new to prolog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for instance, in GNUProlog (or any other having [between](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3)/3):

```
?- findall([X, Y, S, P], (between(1,100,X),between(1,100,Y),1<X,X<Y,S is X+Y,S=<100,P is X*Y),L).
```

Comment: You could optimize it a little: `between(2,100,X), X1 is X + 1, between(X1,100,Y), S is X+Y, ...`. Realizing that this "hides" some of the constraints into the terms rather than having them be move visible/explicit...

Comment: @lurker: of course, but I think that keeping things as simple as possible could be important for a newbie... (btw, I also would use CLP(FD))

Comment: Yeah I understand. And I agree on the CLP(FD) which was my original suggestion in a comment, but guessing the OP didn't want to venture into that library.

Comment: True @lurker, i was hoping for something without using any built-in library except cut `!`, is that possible?